# Nesting a component inside another component without nesting it in the routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently learning Vue JS and practising it by making some apps. I've encountered a problem, which I wasn't able to figure out and I need your help with it.

I have a dashboard component where a user can do CRUD operations for articles and announcements. The template is structured like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="dashboard">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-header">
        <div>
          <router-link to="/settings"
            tag="button"
            class="btn btn-action"><i class="icon website-icon"></i></router-link>
          <router-link to="/settings"
            tag="button"
            class="btn btn-action"><i class="icon messages-icon"></i></router-link>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-title">Admin Panel</div>
        <div>
          <router-link to="/settings"
            tag="button"
            class="btn btn-action"><i class="icon settings-icon"></i></router-link>
          <router-link to="/logout"
            tag="button"
            class="btn btn-action" style="font-size: 1rem"><i class="icon logout-icon"></i></router-link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-nav">
        <ul class="tab tab-block">
          <router-link to="/dashboard" exact
            tag="li"
            class="tab-item"
            active-class="active">Dashboard</router-link>
          <router-link to="/dashboard/articles"
            tag="li"
            class="tab-item"
            active-class="active">Articles</router-link>
          <router-link to="/dashboard/announcements"
            tag="li"
            class="tab-item"
            active-class="active">Announcements</router-link>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div v-if="$route.path=='/dashboard/articles' || $route.path=='/dashboard/announcements'" class="panel-sub-nav">
        <button class="btn btn-unfavorite" style="width: 25%"><i class="icon unfavorite-icon"></i> Unfavorite All</button>
        <div style="width: 50%; text-align: center">0 / 5</div>
        <button v-if="$route.path=='/dashboard/articles'"  class="btn btn-add" style="width: 25%"><i class="icon add-icon"></i> Add Article</button>
        <button v-if="$route.path=='/dashboard/announcements'"  class="btn btn-add" style="width: 25%"><i class="icon add-icon"></i> Add Announcement</button>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The route file is structured like this:

```
import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard'
import ArticleIndex from '../components/ArticleIndex'
import AnnIndex from '../components/AnnIndex'
import Settings from '../components/Settings'

export const routes = [
  { path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard, children: [
    { path: 'articles', component: ArticleIndex },
    { path: 'announcements', component: AnnIndex },
  ] },
  { path: '/settings', component: Settings }
]
```

The problem is that I want users to access settings component inside the dashboard component. But they should access the settings component through `/settings` not `/dashboard/settings`.

Since I've not nested the settings component inside dashboard route. 
Settings component is not opening up inside the dashboard component.

What should I do to have Settings component open inside Dashboard component but be accessed through /settings?

I think is a very easy problem to solve and sure some people already asked this question before but unfortunately, I wasn't able to find an answer.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you could do is keep views separated from your components. So what I would do is the following. Create

- components/Settings.vue

And

- views/DashboardView.vue
- views/SettingsView.vue

And then you import your Settings in `DashboardView` and `SettingsView`

And in your router you of course import your `{x}View` components.